# PUT method in Retrofit 2.0 returns null body

Tags: android, retrofit, put

How to use properly PUT method with `x-www-form-urlencoded`? In Postman everything works fine, but in Android App it doesn't.

My interface:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT(ApiConstants.REGISTER_URL_PART)
    Call<RegisterModel> getStatus(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("fbID") String fbID,
        @Field("gmailID") String gmailID,
        @Field("twitID") String twitID,
        @Field("gender") String gender,
        @Field("birthDate") String birthDate,
        @Field("location") String location,
        @Field("longitude") String longitude,
        @Field("latitude") String latitude,
        @Field("profileImage") String profileImage
    );
```

Factory class:

```
class Factory {
    private static AuthRegisterUserApi service;

    public static AuthRegisterUserApi getInstance() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(AuthRegisterUserApi.class);

        return service;
    }
}
```

Request example:

```
{
  "username": "new_User",
  "email": "some@user.com",
  "password": "qwerty123",
  "gender": "female",
  "birthDate": "1999-12-23",
  "location": "Cracov",
}
```

In app throwing code 400 or 500... Any idea how to corectly implement this PUT method into my app?

Comment: 500/400 response code might be because of you're sending wrong params to the server. Check with server if you're sending valid params that the url is expecting.

Comment: Start by checking server logs why it's giving 400/500. It's impossible to help you without knowing what's wrong

Comment: `D/OkHttp: --> PUT http://ip_address:8400/api/register http/1.1` and `D/OkHttp: username=typek2&email=typek2%40q.q&password=12341234&fbID=&gmailID=&twitID=&gender=male&birthDate=2016-07-04&location=&longitude=50&latitude=50&profileImage=` in Android Monitor

Comment: What you exacltly want to know?

Comment: I hope u have written complete webservice name, that is register.php right?

Comment: What are your constant values for ApiConstants.BASE_URL and ApiConstants.REGISTER_URL_PART?

Comment: `BASE_URL = "http://5.135.147.222:8400";` and
    `REGISTER_URL_PART = "/api/register";`. I don't know how backend looks like, I've got only API to implement in Android App

Comment: Edit your REGISTER_URL_PART with /api/register.php

Comment: @Drv now I've got 404, so this isn't the solution...

Comment: 404 is the error for file or page not found.

Comment: `http://5.135.147.222:8400/api/register` in Postman, so why should I change it?